# .NET Core 6.0 MSTest project - ClassInititalize/ClassCleanUp prevents testrunner from finding tests in Visual Studio 2020

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, .net-6.0

I have a quite courious behavior of my test project. I have one test class like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class TestClass
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test1()
    {
        ...
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test2()
    {
        ...
    }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Init()
    {
        ...
    }

    [TestCleanUp]
    public void Clean()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This works all fine, but when I change from `TestInitialize` to `ClassInititalize`, respectively from `TestCleanUp` to `ClassCleanUp`, the tests are not executed anymore.
They are still visible in the Test-Explorer window, but when I execute the tests from the test tree, directly from the test tree branch leaf, from the code window or from the project context menu, then nothing happens: the output windows just says *"0 tests found"*. The same happens when I try to work with `AssemblyInitialize`/`AssemblyCleanUp`. Visual Studio restart, project rebuild or Nuget update does not solve the problem.

When I switch back to `TestCleanUp`/`TestInitialize` all works fine again ...

Is there a hidden switch I have to use to be able to use `ClassInitialize`/`ClassCleanUp`/`AssemblyCleanUp`/`AssemblyInitialize`?

Comment: `ClassInitialize` and `AssemblyInitialize` methods must be `static`. If you go to the Output window and switch the "show output from" to "Tests", you should see the test runner complain to that effect. It appears to be a UI shortcoming that this error message isn't clearly surfaced.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Changing initialize and cleanup method to static has no efffect - the tests are still not found by the test runner ...

Comment: Read the output, it'll tell you what's wrong. But I'll spoiler it for you: they also need to take a `TestContext` parameter.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Thanks! I did not scroll that long way to the right - but now I can see the explanations as well :) - Fixed and it works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of JeroenMostert (see comments of question), the issue has been solved.

I rewrote the initialize method as follow:

```
[ClassInitialize]
static public void Initialize(TestContext context)
{
    ...;
}
```

Then all tests are found and therefore executed again.

Comment: Hi user1470240, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as the answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)